# Vertex AI Instance Out of Disk Space

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I accidentally ran out of disk space on my Vertex AI instance. There's no way to connect to it by any means now. Using the jupyter failed as there's not enough disk space:
`OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device`

I tried to increase disk space for both boot and data disks using `gcloud compute disks resize`, but it still doesn't work despite disk space being shown as increased in the machine info panel.

Also tried connecting through ssh but got timeouts. My guess is that it's still caused by disk space.

So is there any ways to recover the instance without a hard reset?